# How to set same md-checkbox focus outline for all focus sources

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

When md-checkbox is focused using keyboard, there's outline around it.
But when focus is set programmatically, there is no visual indicator. Is there any way to make it look the same?
[image]

Comment: Could you show your way of doing? This way works: https://plnkr.co/edit/W2UWkVuR2bjwRr196LcA?p=preview

Comment: Actually I'm not using it directly..I'll try to explain. On almost all browsers  tabbing between checkboxes works fine. On Firefox sometimes checkbox is focused but there is no visual effect. I checked DOM and discovered that when this bug occurs, checkbox input has assigned class cdk-program-focused instead of  cdk-keyboard-focused, so I thought it's default behaviour when focus is triggered programmaticaly. After your example I see that I was wrong. Do you have any idea what could cause that strange behaviour on Firefox? I cannot provide any code because it's part of a very large project.

Comment: any updates on this ? did you try the answer I provided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripple is a click/focus event. If you want to have the ripple effect after setting the checkbox programmatically, you need to focus the element from your code. For that you also need to add a reference for your control.

In your template, add a reference variable to your checkbox e.g. `customCheckbox`:

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" #customCheckbox>Check me!</md-checkbox>
```

... and in your code, you need to call `focus()` method on this control:

```
// Import MdCheckbox in your ts file
import { MdCheckbox } from '@angular/material';

// Declare customCheckbox in your class
@ViewChild('customCheckbox') private customCheckbox: MdCheckbox;

// Use this line to focus the checkbox programmatically where you want.
this.customCheckbox.focus();
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbpyae?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).